I have been using flutterflow to create an app but when I try and test the app on my phone it says that my window is too small, could someone assist?
I have been using flutter flow to create an app and I wanted to see how it looked on my phone however I can't test flutter flow app since when I try on my iPhone it says my window is too small and it won't let me do anything.
Does anyone know the solution to this?

It sounds like you're trying to preview the app on your phone using app.flutterflow.io, which is the place you go to edit and build the app, not preview it. In order to view the app on a real device you'll need to use Local Run, publish to the web or publish to a testing track on the app store / play store. You'll find info on how to do all that in the docs. Here's a link to the publishing section of FlutterFlow docs:
https://docs.flutterflow.io/deployment/pre-checks-before-publishing/
